# How to make a folder dynamically with PHP

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

I want to allow the user to add something, and get a folder:

```
example.com/foo
```

But I DONT want the folder to actually be there, I want it to be made instantaneously, so that I can still use the directory foo for private files (If I wanted to).

The name of the folder will be stored in a mySQL database, so all that remains is to map it. But how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for. Instead of doing `example.com/foo`, use `example.com/something/foo`. Then use an .htaccess rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?something/(\w+)$ fake.php?file=$1
```

Then you could have `fake.php` do everything that you need it to.

Comment: I'm presuming that the user doesn't see the redirect, only the server and the PHP page? If I made PHP get the current URL, would it return the server-side URL or the one shown by the browser?

Comment: @drnessie Correct, the user has no idea what happened. When PHP returns the "current" URL, it returns what the *user* sees (assuming you're building the current URL with the $_SERVER array).